# How to remove name suggestion menu that appears on top of textfield in swift iOS 16?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, ios16

I have created a base text field (**`UITextField`**) to make it customizable, and used this text field to show a drop-down on it. Whenever I open that drop-down it shows suggestions on top of that text field as shown in the image below.
[image: Here as you can see there is a suggestion for a drop-down]

It appears for iOS 16 only, for the rest it is not showing.

Does anyone know how to remove/Hide this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting autoCorrectionType to false?

```
textField.autocorrectionType = .no
```

Comment: Yes I have tried that but it is not working. Tried with the storyboard as well.